# Is the Grassmannian of a Banach space an infinite dimensional manifold?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, grassmannians, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Grassmannian of complemented subspaces in a Banach space is a Banach manifold. This is explained for example in the thesis of Douady and is rather analogous to the finite-dimensional case.

I would like to ask if there is some known structure of an infinite dimensional manifold on the Grassmannian of closed, but not necessarily complemented subspaces.